# Multiple range keys in couchdb views

Tags: http, view, key, couchdb, nosql

I've been searching for a solution since few hours without success...

I just want to do this request in couchdb with a view:

```
select * from database where (id >= 3000000 AND id <= 3999999) AND gyro_y >= 1000
```

I tried this:

```
function(doc) {
    if(doc.id && doc.Gyro_y){
        emit([doc.id,doc.Gyro_y], null);
    }
}
```

Here is my document (record in couchdb):

```
{
   "_id": "f97968bee9674259c75b89658b09f93c",
   "_rev": "3-4e2cce33e562ae502d6416e0796fcad1",
   "id": "30000002",
   "DateHeure": "2016-06-16T02:08:00Z",
   "Latitude": 1000,
   "Longitude": 1000,
   "Gyro_x": -242,
   "Gyro_y": 183,
   "Gyro_z": -156,
   "Accel_x": -404,
   "Accel_y": -2424,
   "Accel_z": -14588
}
```

I then do an HTTP request like so:

```
http://localhost:5984/arduino/_design/filter/_view/bygyroy?startkey=["3000000",1000]&endkey=["3999999",9999999]&include_docs=true
```

I get this as an answer:

```
{
    total_rows: 10,
    offset: 8,
    rows: [{
    id: "f97968bee9674259c75b89658b09f93c",
    key: [
    "01000002",
    183
    ],
    value: null,
    doc: {
        _id: "f97968bee9674259c75b89658b09f93c",
        _rev: "3-4e2cce33e562ae502d6416e0796fcad1",
        id: "30000002",
        DateHeure: "2016-06-16T02:08:00Z",
        Latitude: 1000,
        Longitude: 1000,
        Gyro_x: -242,
        Gyro_y: 183,
        Gyro_z: -156,
        Accel_x: -404,
        Accel_y: -2424,
        Accel_z: -14588
    }
}
]
}
```

So it's working for the **id** but it's not working for the second key **gyro_y**.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

When you specify arrays as your start/end keys, the results are filtered in a "cascade". In other words, it moves from left to right, and only if something was matched by the previous key, will it be matched by the next key.

In this case, you'll only find `Gyro_y >= 1000` when that document also matches the first condition of `3000000 <= id <= 3999999`.

Your SQL example does not translate exactly to what you are doing in CouchDB. In SQL, it'll find both conditions and then find the intersection amongst your resulting rows. I would read up on [view collation](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/couchapp/views/collation.html?highlight=view%20collation) to understand these inner-workings of CouchDB.

To solve your problem right now, I would simply switch the order you are emitting your keys. By putting the `Gyro_y` value first, you should get the results you've described.

Comment: But then it's the **id** value which is ignored.

Comment: If you need a pure `OR` with ranges like you get in SQL, you won't be able to accomplish it with a single map-reduce. If my suggestion doesn't work, you might need to use 2 views and then compute the intersection in your application.